# Create a dynamic matlab function using arrayfun or some other way

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to create a dynamic functions in length with multiple inputs, tried doing it this way but  it seems over kill am guessing slow too, is there a better way of doing this to be compact and fast.

Problem want to create a cos with inputs from nX3 matrix `sum(A*cos(W*t + F))` where A, W, F are columns from the matrix sum them all up then divide by its norm. Here is what I have so far .

```
% example input can have n rows
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; 
item.fre = 0;
item.amp = 0;
item.pha = 0;
items = repmat(item, size(A, 1), 1);
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    items(i).fre = A(i, 1);
    items(i).amp = A(i, 2);
    items(i).pha = A(i, 3);
end

fun = @(t) sum(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) i.amp*cos(2*pi*t*i.fre + i.pha), items, 'un',0)));

% test run all this steps just to get a norm vector 
time = 1:10;
testSignal = fun(time);
testSignal = testSignal/norm(testSignal);
```

Comment: What is a dynamic function?

Comment: Why not use normal vectorization?

Comment: Dynamic function are function that changes in size and properties I don't know what matlab calls such a thing but its what am trying to create like in the sample above and normal vectorization i don't know what that is .

Comment: Do you understand what vectorization is? Matlab operates on variable sized inputs out of the box. It sounds like you're doing 10x work for no reason.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you have M rows in A N time samples, do you want to take the sum along the time or the A dimension? In other words, do you want an output of size M or size N?

Comment: Type in MATLAB: `t=1:10, f=[1;2], f.*t`. Look at the printed values. I’m sure you can expand from there out. It’s not nearly as complicated as you’re trying to make it. Forget about anonymous functions and structs and cell arrays. You can compute this in a single line.

Comment: What with the riddles and short clues its not a homework or competition, am no expert in matlab..
Just want to do a fast computation then back to programming. vectorization then how can you access the property Matrix f by index in equation in any order. Here is what I got
t = 1:10; f = [1 10 55; 22 4 100; 5 6 70];i = 1:size(f, 1);
y = sum( f([i,2])*cos( 2*pi*t.*f([i,1]) + f([i,3])) ); am getting error
Inner matrix dimensions must agree. If you can compute this in a single line
show me...thank you

Comment: Index a column using `f(:,1)`. Use `.*` for element-wise multiplication (`*` is matrix multiplication). If you want to work with MATLAB, spend an hour or two learning the basics, it’ll save you a lot of time in the long run: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html

Comment: Matlab indeed has many features supporting dynamic functions. There are [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), `varargin`/`varargout` support, and all that is in addition to multi-dimensional array. These features can allow us to write well-centralized and adaptable code but they have significant performance implications.

Comment: In any case, it's a waste of time for the answers to explain them without context and thus the ability to show when and why these features are pertinent; and potentially harmful without  the examples to discuss how to provision for performance implications . **Having everything defined with precision, using minimal, reproducible examples, and showing desired behaviors are all parts and parcels of StackOverflow.** Thinking about dynamic inputs and such is good. It's unfortunate that this question cannot lead a discussion into the useful features of Matlab by failing the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with a comment made by Cris Luengo to forget about anonymous functions and structures, you should try the simplest solution first.  It looks like you're trying to add cosines with different amplitudes, frequencies, and phases.  Here is how I would do it to make it very readable

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; 
freq = A(:, 1);
amp = A(:, 2);
phase = A(:, 3);
time = 1:.01:10;
testSignal = zeros(size(time));
for i = 1:length(freq)
    testSignal = testSignal + amp(i) * cos(2*pi*freq(i) * time + phase(i));
end

testSignal = testSignal/norm(testSignal);
plot(time, testSignal)
grid on
```

You could eliminate the `amp`, `phase`, and `freq` variables by accessing the columns of `A` directly, but that would make the code much less readable.

Comment: Thank you for the help, It was like milking ants for helpful information here....compute in a single line...that can sink ships